# How do I use Powershell regex to convert "" into \"?

Tags: powershell, csv, escaping

I have a Powershell script that produces CSV. Only it double quotes double-quotes in a string, whereas every other piece of software I use (in the Unix world anyway) uses \" inside a string instead of "" to mean one double-quote.

Using Powershell regex's, how do I turn this:

```
"""C:\Java\jre8\bin\java"" -Djava.library.path=""C:\some\path\lib"" -classpath ""some;long;classpath"" com.foo.app.Main"
```

into this?

```
"\"C:\Java\jre8\bin\java\" -Djava.library.path=\"C:\some\path\lib\" -classpath \"some;long;classpath\" com.foo.app.Main"
```

I've tried using the supposed Powershell escape character (backtick), but haven't been able to get the conversion to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression with a positive lookahead zerolength assertion.

```
$String='"""C:\Java\jre8\bin\java"" -Djava.library.path=""C:\some\path\lib"" -classpath ""some;long;classpath"" com.foo.app.Main"
$String
$String -replace '"(?="[^"])','\'
```

yields:

```
"""C:\Java\jre8\bin\java"" -Djava.library.path=""C:\some\path\lib"" -classpath ""some;long;classpath"" com.foo.app.Main"
"\"C:\Java\jre8\bin\java\" -Djava.library.path=\"C:\some\path\lib\" -classpath \"some;long;classpath\" com.foo.app.Main"
```

Comment: You answer works, thanks.  Unfortunately, it didn't fix my particular problem, because it turns out the string only had single " in it, but it was the | Export-Csv -Path output.csv that was doubling up the ".  Not sure if I can fix that without reading in output.csv and transforming *that*.

Comment: Looks like "" for " in CSV is a "standard."  I guess I'll just remove the extra " in whatever process reads the CSV.